# C#. Torrent client. Peer handshake. Strange peer responses

Tags: c#, bittorrent, torrent

I'm developing my own torrent client(for self-improvement) and during the step of peer handshake I'm constantly retrieving "incorrect" responses like that one:
[image: strange response]

by specification(https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Handshake) I need to send the request following the next pattern:
//handshake: <info_hash><peer_id> as a byte array.
code to generate peer handshake byte array(GenerateHandShakeMessage method):

```
public class PeerHandShake
    {
        //pstrlen
        public const string ProtocolStringLength = "19";

        //pstr
        public const string ProtocolString = "BitTorrent protocol";

        public byte[] InfoHash { get; set; }

        public string PeerId { get; set; }

        public PeerHandShake(string peerId, byte[] infoHash)
        {
            PeerId = peerId;
            InfoHash = infoHash;
        }

        //handshake: <pstrlen><pstr><reserved><info_hash><peer_id>
        public byte[] GenerateHandShakeMessage()
        {
            var handshakeMessage = new List<byte>();

            var protocolPart = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{ProtocolStringLength}{ProtocolString}");
            handshakeMessage.AddRange(protocolPart);

            //Supported version is 1.0 that is why all reserved 8 bytes are zeros
            var reservedPart = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(new[] { '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00' });
            handshakeMessage.AddRange(reservedPart);

            handshakeMessage.AddRange(InfoHash);

            var peerPart = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{PeerId}");
            handshakeMessage.AddRange(peerPart);

            return handshakeMessage.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

This is how am I sending it and receiving the response(this is just handshake test code):

```
public static void SendRequest(string endpoint, int port, byte[] message)
{
    try
    {
        var listener = new TcpClient();
        listener.Connect(endpoint, port);
        var stream = listener.GetStream();
        stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        listener.Client.Send(message);

        var data = new byte[1000];
        var responseData = string.Empty;

        var bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        listener.Client.Close();
        listener.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

I'm sending the 69 bytes which as ASCII string would be displayed as:
"19BitTorrent protocol\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0???fq?[??w?Tb?\u000e/5E??-PT-0001-01678496022"

And I supposed to receive a string which is following the same pattern however I do receive something like that(and quite often the response is different):
"?\u0001)R?)Q0???q????_??\u0010\u0001?b???;\v??\u0005?G??P3?}??\r ;?%8?a???+\u0010?\f??H?\u001f\u0010\n?OSA\u001e[\u001eR;?D?E]^?y?\u0013TN?u7I?8\u0016?\u0003\u001c\a??t?\u000f}*?Tv\u001aW(-?^?u%\u001e??J??]5?I?????\u0005\n??H?;}T??1?9?\u001e??????????U$?P???6DZ??\u0012?\u0014#4<\u001a?S?Pt???{K??r???o?(A{?\b< ?y???4?w\u0016?W)?N?f??q???"o\u000fR?\u0015???l??????\u007f\u0001"

When I was running the same torrent file via uTorrent with WireShark monitoring, I noticed that uTorrent is accepting such handshakes.
Could somebody point me, what do I missed?

PS: infohash is generated correctly, because I'm able to get the peers' ip addresses from tracker with it.

PPS: I would appreciate any help, because I'm stuck with it for a long time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handshake begins with a byte set to 19<sub>base10</sub> or 0x13. Since you're sending the string "19" (2 bytes) your handshake is already incorrect and the peer apparently tries to respond with something else, perhaps the obfuscated protocol handshake.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much for the answer. Now I'm receiving the correct handshakes!